# How can I append two list with eachother?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to append one with another, like this:

```
a = [['bmw'], ['audi'], ['benz'], ['honda']]
b = [[12,2], [3,4], [7,5], [6,23]]
```

new list should be like this:

```
n = [['bmw', 12, 2], ['audi', 3, 4], ['benz', 7, 5], ['honda', 6, 23]]
```

I try this but it didn't work:

```
for i, j in a, b:
    a[i].append(b[j])
```

Comment: `[i + j for i, j in zip(a, b)]`

Answer (score 5):

Use list comprehension:

```py
[i+j for i,j in zip(a, b)]
```

Results in:

```py
[['bmw', 12, 2], ['audi', 3, 4], ['benz', 7, 5], ['honda', 6, 23]]
```

Comment: Thanks man... this code worked perfect

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it right, you should use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
a = [['bmw'], ['audi'], ['benz'], ['honda']]
b = [[12,2], [3,4], [7,5], [6,23]]

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    i.extend(j)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[['bmw', 12, 2], ['audi', 3, 4], ['benz', 7, 5], ['honda', 6, 23]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for el1, el2 in zip(a, b):
  el1.extend(el2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and concatenation:

```
a = [['bmw'], ['audi'], ['benz'], ['honda']]
b = [[12,2], [3,4], [7,5], [6,23]]
c = [item[0] + item[1] for item in zip(a, b)]
```

Which yields:

```
['bmw', 12, 2]
['audi', 3, 4]
['benz', 7, 5]
['honda', 6, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
result = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Results in:

```py
[['bmw', 12, 2], ['audi', 3, 4], ['benz', 7, 5], ['honda', 6, 23]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` & `lambda` function, `*` unpacking to a list and `+` list concatenation:

```
res = [*map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b)]
print(res)
```